# UWP App with SQL database connection problem

Tags: sql, uwp

I have a lot of errors with my UWP for Windows 10 for which I need SQL connection. I have errors like SQLFreeHandle is not defined, ( I have the library)

Here is the code: https://hastebin.com/ojoqotezuv.cpp

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Your code belongs here in order to form a complete and answerable question.  I, personally, don't "do links to".  :)

Comment: ODBC is not yet supported in UWP platform. So your exist library is only for desktop apps.